# W3 Total Cache JavaScript minify WordPress website issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, minify, w3-total-cache

I need your assistance to fix the following.

I updated the W3 Total Cache plugin on my WordPress website, https://codersfort.com/. Could someone please assist me in fixing this problem? After downloading and activating the plugin, I minified JavaScript, which is why the website's main page just displays codes. There are no issues with the rest of the pages.

I have deactivates the plugin and nothing happened, can anyone help me get my web site to normal?

Comment: activate it again , go to settings, and make sure all the cache are disabled, then clear all the cache, then deactivate it, you may also have remove so lines of code added in wp-config file, also, if you search on google there multiple blogs on how to properly remove it from your site once its activated.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, ill do that !

Comment: Please post the error message as text here on SO instead of linking to your website.